# How to deal with recursion Stackoverflows in java

Tags: java, string, recursion, stack

While performing recursions for calculating the string permutations or combinations require new objects to be created at each level of recursion but sooner this leads to stackoverflows, in order to prevent that I tried to simulate the scenarios on character arrays or string builder but the problem comes when at each level of recursion complexity increases, therefore, managing character array or string builder also become too complex.

How to resolve such situations here is the code i wrote:-

```
private static int solve(int num) {

    if (num == 1) {
        return 6;
    }
    combination("", "");
    return list.size();
}

private static int combination(String ch, String prev) {

    if (!ch.isEmpty() && ch.split(" ").length == arrInput.length)
        list.add(performSum(ch));

    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < creditScore.length; i++) {
            prev = ch;
            if (ch.isEmpty())
                ch = "" + creditScore[i];
            else
                ch = ch + " " + creditScore[i];
            combination(ch, prev);
            ch = prev;
        }
    }
    return list.size();
}
```

The scenario could be like suppose there are combinations to be found out for students total score, where:-

```
credits allocated ranges from 1<= N <=5
Number of subjects from  1<= N <=100
Grade points from 5<=N<=10

Therefore as an example, a combination of score could be (1*6)+(2*10)+(4*7)....N subjects
```

Find total distinct score combinations.

Comment: Can you share one specific scenario where you face this?

Comment: Take a look at `tail call optimization` or `tail recursion`. It is an optimization technique for avoiding stackoverflow error on recursive calls.

Comment: Java does not support tail call recursion.

Comment: Nor this is a tail recursion

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure your recursion is not infinite. Otherwise... no point trying to solve.

> f(x) = f(x-1) will be infinite

- Reformulate the problem, try to make it not explode at all, or as quickly as it does. Try to find simplifications that avoid further processing, etc.
- Memoization, store result of previous runs so you can have a `deeper` starting point.

  For f(x) = f(x-1), you can store r[i] where i = f(i*k), in other words, you store the result every k steps. If x is massive you probably want to store geometrically: k^i.

  Check the lowest common ancestor problem on trees for an example of storing every k^i steps.
- Recursion can be transformed into a loop, check DP, Dynamic Programming. Here, what grows is an state array however, so you still cant have infinite recursion.
- If the recursion needs do not grow geometrically and can be built upon, eg.

  > a) f(x) = f(x-1), x > 0; f(0) = 1
  >   or
  >   b) f(x) = f(x-1) + f(x-2) + f(x-3), x > 0; f(x) = 1, x <= 0

  Instead of solving f(x) you can start from f(0) and build towards x and, after k steps, store the temporary progress into a pending-work stack and quit your recursion, then restart evaluation from your save point. On the first example you only need to store your current f(x), on the second example you only need to know f(x), f(x-1) and f(x-2).
- If the temporary storage needs grow with each call, and you cant turn it into a problem with fixed requirements. Then you can save to disk. If the needs exceed your disk capacity + other storage then you can't solve it.
- For Java, use the Xmx flag to allow more RAM to be used.
- Finally, your example problem looks like a combinatorial problem, so it most likely has a mathematical solution that doesnt require recursion, so it would fall under reformulation. If that is it, check `combinatorics` and the math exchange.